# How do I remove concrete that has splattered on my brick pavers?

Tags: concrete, cleaning, brick, patio

We installed a brick patio, and splatter from wet-cutting the bricks ended up on the installed bricks.

How do I clean it?

Comment: A closeup photo of the surface would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pressure washer with the widest angle nozzle held about 2 ft or more away from the pavers will take off the residue. Don't get too close or the intense water pressure will also take away the smooth finish of the pavers..

Answer (score 0):

Muriatic acid will literally eat away concrete. I use when repointing bricks. It may discolor the pavers so you will need to test it first.